# Кастомная отрисовка TreeView в Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, treeview

Реально ли отрисовать Tree View в Delphi не только по вертикали вниз но и по горизонтали в сторону?

Подкиньте примеры реализации кастомной отрисовки.. спасибо!

[image: пример отображения]